# Using telegram bot to send messages in non-blocking loop

Tags: python, event-handling, coroutine, python-telegram-bot

I have a python script which is intended to parse and send error logs to a Telegram channel. I have used python-telegram-bot library to send messages to the Telegram channel `bot.send_message(chat_id=channel_id, text='Hello, World!')`. While I run the script it asked me to launch it with a coroutine and I made it as it was required `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited MessageProcessor.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=msg_content, parse_mode='markdown') RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`.

Like this..

```
async def sendtelegram(message):
       ## some code to process the message ### 
       await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=msg_content, parse_mode='markdown')
```

so far so good. The code flow starts by parsing new incoming log messages in a log file and put the parsed message in a queue. After that, there is a method that pulls out the parsed message from the queue and start the coroutine to send the messages.

```
def process_messages(self): 
      while True: 
              try: 
                  message = self.message_queue.dequeue()
                  asyncio.run(MessageProcessor.sendtelegram(message)) 
              except queue.Empty: 
                  time.sleep(0.1)
                  continue
```

The problem is that the while loop blocks the event loop of the coroutine and causes exceptions

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/scripts/./grok_parser_1-6.py", line 95, in <module>
    message_processor.process_messages()
  File "/root/scripts/./grok_parser_1-6.py", line 82, in process_messages
    asyncio.run(MessageProcessor.sendtelegram(message))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/root/scripts/./grok_parser_1-6.py", line 77, in sendtelegram
    await MessageProcessor.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=msg_content, parse_mode='markdown')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 525, in decorator
    result = await func(self, *args, **kwargs)  # skipcq: PYL-E1102
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 846, in send_message
    return await self._send_message(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 703, in _send_message
    result = await self._post(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 613, in _post
    return await self._do_post(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 641, in _do_post
    return await request.post(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 200, in post
    result = await self._request_wrapper(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 342, in _request_wrapper
    raise NetworkError(f"Unknown error in HTTP implementation: {exc!r}") from exc
telegram.error.NetworkError: Unknown error in HTTP implementation: RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
```

It's clear that issue is caused by conflicts between the While loop, responsible of getting the dequeued messages, and the main event loop of the coroutine.

So,

1- Is it possible to launch the coroutine outside of the while loop.. how?
2- Or can we send the telegram messages without a coroutine?
3- Or rewrite the code without the while loop, maybe with event-based logic?

please recommend the simplest approach to solve my problem.